# Using "AND" operation to select hashes from array of hashes in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, select, hash, include

```
input = [ {"name" => "adam",  "nick" => ["kuruvi", "cali"] },
          {"name" => "eve",   "nick" => ["cali"]           },
          {"name" => "enoch", "nick" => []                 },    
          {"name" => "ebe",   "nick" => ["test", "wrong"]  },
          {"name" => "fred",  "nick" => ["da"]             } ]
```

I want to select hashes which contains `"da"` & `"cali"` in `"nick"`.

```
input.select do |d|
  d["nick"].include?("cali")
end
```

gives

```
[{"name"=>"adam", "nick"=>["kuruvi", "cali"]},
 {"name"=>"eve", "nick"=>["cali"]}]
```

How can we include two parameters in check. Eg: `include?("cali","da")` so that my result will be

```
 [{"name"=>"adam", "nick"=>["kuruvi", "cali"]},
  {"name"=>"eve", "nick"=>["cali"]},
  {"name" => "fred",  "nick" => ["da"]}]
```

Tried this

```
 i = ["da","cali"]
 input.select do |d|
   d["nick"].all? { |v| i.include? v }
 end

=> [{"name" => "adam",  "nick" => ["kuruvi", "cali"]},
    {"name" => "eve",   "nick" => ["cali"]},
    {"name" => "enoch", "nick" => []},
    {"name" => "fred",  "nick" => ["da"]}]
```

(but this returns hashes with `"nick"=[]` also)

Answer (score 2):

On the basis of your desired result you are referring to "or", not "and". The following uses the method [Array#&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-26).

```
input.reject { |h| (h["nick"] & ["cali", "da"]).empty? }
  #=> [{"name"=>"adam", "nick"=>["kuruvi", "cali"]},
  #    {"name"=>"eve", "nick"=>["cali"]},
  #    {"name"=>"fred", "nick"=>["da"]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two different `include?` tests:

```
l = d['nick']
l.include?('da') && l.include?('cali')
```

You could also try:

```
(d['nick'] & %w[ da cali ]).length == 2
```

Or if you want you could write your own method to test for overlap like that, perhaps even patching it into Array as `include_all?`

Comment: Tried this::        i = ["da","cali"]

input.select do |d|
   d["nick"].all? { |v|  i.include? v }
end

Comment: the above returns  {"name" => "enoch", "nick" => []} also..where "nick" is []

Comment: The `all?` call isn't in the right spot there. That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `all?`, you can use `any?` to achieve the desired result.

```
input.select do |d|
  d["nick"].any? { |h| ['cali','da'].include?(h) }
end
```

This returns

```
[{"name"=>"adam", "nick"=>["kuruvi", "cali"]}, 
 {"name"=>"eve",  "nick"=>["cali"]}, 
 {"name"=>"fred", "nick"=>["da"]}]
```